# Filament not extruding

Tags: prusa-i3, extrusion, anet-a8

I've recently bought an Anet A8, and haven't been getting good prints with it. I noticed there was filament leaking from the top of the hot end and pooling, eventually dripping over onto my prints. I took the hot end off to clean it, and when I put it back on and tightened it, my printer wouldn't extrude anymore. I took the motor apart, and there was a lot of filament shavings inside. I tried tightening the screw that splits the bearing and gear that feeds the filament since I thought it may be getting caught in there.

I can manually push filament through and it works fine. There's no jam, so I'm thinking it IS something to do with that, but I don't really know what to do. Now that I've done this also, I feel as if I've screwed up the e steps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The spindle screws on the gear are shipped not tight enough. Try taking the fan off and make sure the gear is seated properly and tighten the screws down. Here's a video that might help. https://youtu.be/zkZKzF3J3NA

Comment: I did look at that video initially and tried repositioning it to no avail. I ended up taking my fan and heatsink off, pushing the bar at the top as far up as it goes, and tightening the pivot. This seems to have worked. I just keep the fan and heatsink off now, as it happened again when I put them back on after one print.

Comment: You could try some lock tight on the threads.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? It seems to be ok without the heatsink, so fingers crossed it doesn't screw up again!

Comment: You might want the heat sink for large prints. You can get lock tite that comes in a tube like a glue stick. Apply it to the threads and it should keep it from becoming loose again.. But it may require heat to remove if you ever have to take it apart again.